# Can't open windows 7 help files standalone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

In Windows 7, if I run a game like Minesweeper or Mahjong Titans, then choose "help" from the game's menu, I get a standalone help window, from which I can navigate to other topics (presumably all the help files that came with the OS).  Note that I always have "offline help" selected, not "online help."

I would like to open these files from a button-click event in C#.  The problem is, I don't know where these files are stored, or even with what extension.

When I have the standalone help window open, the task manager lists the process as "HelpPane.exe" which is located in C:\Windows.  If I try to double-click on HelpPane.exe, nothing happens.

If I right-click on the help window and choose "view source", I see that it is basically a web page.  An example <body> tag is:

`<BODY helptype="toc" helpurl="mshelp://windows/?tocid=ebd9c148-6e8d-4359-83d5-f4b700ab2f8f" helpsource="local" Lang="en-US">`

Can I access mshelp://windows/... from a C# program?  Or is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HelpPane.exe is an out-of-process COM server.  You can activate it and get it to display content in your own C# program easily.  To get started, use Project + Add Reference and select c:\windows\helppane.exe.  That creates the interop library from the COM type library embedded in helppane.exe, generated with the "APClientHelpPane" namespace.

A sample program that displays the Windows Help Topics content file:

```
using System;
using WinHelp = APClientHelpPane;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var obj = new WinHelp.HxHelpPaneServer();
        string docpath = @"C:\Windows\Help\Windows\ContentStore\en-US\windowsclient.mshc";
        obj.DisplayContents(docpath);
    }
}
```

Tested on the en-US edition of Windows 8.1.  No real idea how much luck you'll have with it on Windows 7, I suspect you'll have to modify the path to the .mshc file.  This should concern you of course.  Microsoft also has no obligation to keep this working on future versions of Windows, this Automation interface is not documented.  Reverse-engineering the topic names for the various Windows programs is not that obvious, I suspect you can use the mshelp:// URLs that you find by inspecting the displayed content but how stable they are across Windows versions is something you'll have to find out the hard way.

The [Microsoft Help Viewer SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627473.aspx) should interest you.  MSHC authoring tools are mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thehelpguy/archive/2010/01/26/help-authoring-tool-hat-support-for-help-viewer-1-0.aspx).

Comment: I am experiencing joy!  This code works brilliantly.  I thought I would have to change the .mshc path to 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\content\Microsoft\store` 
since that's what shows up when I search the hard drive for any .mshc file, but the path you gave works.  And this is a program I'm writing for my own use, so I'm not too concerned about forward-compatibility.  Now I'm off to unravel the specific topic names, thanks to the links you gave.

Comment: Update:  both paths for the .mshc file work, and open the same help page.  Weird.

Comment: It is probably the same file.  Microsoft likes using hard links to keep Windows compatible.  Just like all the files in c:\windows\system32 are actually stored in c:\windows\winsxs.

Comment: It seems finding the topic id's is easier than expected:  Right-click on the help page and "view source", then use the "helpurl" listed in the <body> tag.  

For example, `obj.DisplayContents(@"mshelp://windows/?tocid=ebd9c148-6e8d-4359-83d5-f4b700ab2f8f");` displays the help topics for the game Minesweeper.  

Can't thank you enough, Hans Passant!